# Using PHP variable within ACF repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) repeater fields, the markup should look like this to initiate the loop.

```
<? if( have_rows('my-repeating-field) ): ?>
<? endif ?>
```

However, I would like to make this dynamic, meaning I use another PHP variable as part of the if() code, something like as follows:

```
<? $variable = get_field('my-variable-field'); ?>

<? if( have_rows("'" . $variable . "-repeating-field" . "'") ): ?>
<? endif ?>
```

However, this is not working. Is there a way I can do this with ACF/PHP? Seems pretty simple to me?

Comment: did you checked `$variable` has any value or not? 
you can  try `$row_field = $variable . '-repeating-field';` and then use `var_dump` to check if it has corrected value or not. then if it is correct try `if(have_rows($row_field)...`

Comment: Yes it outputs as expected, but still doesn't work. I.e <? $variable . '-repeating-field' = variablevalue-repeating-field ?>

Comment: Is  "variablevalue-repeating-field" an ACF repeater field name?

Comment: You're quoting the string in a weird way, so the value will have single quotes in it... `have_rows($variable . '-repeating-field')` should be enough

Comment: Cheers @naththedeveloper - this works! If you want to put it into an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: @dungey_140 glad you got it working, I've added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're concatenating the string in a way which would cause the end value being passed to `have_rows` to have quotes inside of it. You only need to concatenate the value and the end of the string, and that should be enough.

```
have_rows($variable . '-repeating-field')
```